# Can I edit a site name and the associated mailbox name at a later date?

Tags: edit, rename, site-mailboxes

I've been tasked with designing a simple site for a document repository for my company but while it's being built, I'd like to call it Test Document Library and when we are happy with it, edit the name to remove "Test"

I understand that when you create a site, an email address for that site is also created, so if I change the name, will the email address also be changed or do I need to create a brand new site and then import all the data then delete the Test site?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about the Site MailBox concept. When the site is created the site mailbox App will be there by default in site content. so once the site owner clicks that app then only it will provision the site mailbox email ID like SMO-sitename@office365.domain.com. so whenever you change the title of the site, it will not reflect any changes on the email ID.

So we need to manually change the email ID using the Exchange powershell mode.

if you are looking for the same solution , please let me know i will post the cmdlets to change the email ID. for this no need to delete or create a new site.